# Constructor CustomKeyboard(LoginDialog, int, int) is undefined

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I'm attempting to implement a custom keyboard in my app and I need to use it during a login dialog prompt.

I've attempted to implement the example found here:

http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

However I'm getting an error in my code when I attempt to implement it on the line:

```
mCustomKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd );
```

Stating that "The constructor CustomKeyboard(LoginDialog, int, int) is undefined    LoginDialog.java"

I've tried changing the constructor from:

```
   public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
mHostActivity= host;
```

to

```
 public CustomKeyboard(LoginDialog loginDialog, int viewid, int layoutid) {
        mHostActivity= loginDialog;
```

but it causes a domino effect of other issues in the code so I'm thinking there is a better way of implementing this constructor.

### LoginDialog.java

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment implements
ActionCompletedListener {
    private View view;
    private String whichActivity = "";
    private TextView error;
    CustomKeyboard mCustomKeyboard;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.HoloDarkDialog));
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
        mCustomKeyboard = new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview,
                R.xml.hexkbd);
```

### CustomKeyboard.java

```
  public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
    mHostActivity= host;
    mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
    // Hide the standard keyboard initially
    mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

P.S.

Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated... and additional information/source can/will be provided promptly by request.

Full source can be found here:

http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that by supplying `this` at the constructor, you are pointing to the `LoginDialog` which was inherited from `DialogFragment`, which is subclass of `Fragment`, while constructor expects `Activity` or any of it's subclasses. I don't know the full code, but if you need to supply `Activity` to constructor, you can use `HostingActivity.this`. If you want to work with this constructor:

```
public CustomKeyboard(LoginDialog loginDialog, int viewid, int layoutid)
```

you can get hosting activity by calling `loginDialog.getActivity()` and you can get corresponding view with `loginDialog.getView()`

Comment: The eclipse error went away but I'm getting a force close issue - any ideas/suggestions?

http://pastebin.com/e65kyPrZ

Comment: @user3585761 I believe it's another issue to dive in, but anyway, `CustomKeyboard.registerEditText(CustomKeyboard.java:150)` is required to say anything

Comment: What do you mean "CustomKeyboard.registerEditText is required to say anything"

Comment: @user3585761 I mean this function is needed to find the root cause of crash. But anyway, it's another question

Answer (score 0):

```
registerEditText(int resid)
```

searches for the **EditText** in the Activity View.

You should add the Dialog View to the **CustomKeyboard** constructor, and let **registerEditText** search there for the **EditText**.